# Using rpyc to run gui based application on remote windows machine

Tags: python, c++, windows, rpyc

I'd like to run a gui based user-interactive process on remote windows machine. Here's a simple naive example of such process that opens a messageBox:

```
void main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, NULL, "my window", MB_OK);
    sleep(100000);
}
```

The medium for running is rpyc server and the flow looks like this from the client side :

```
conn = rpyc.classic.connect(remote_ip)
proc = conn.modules.subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
proc.communicate()
```

and on the other side I simply activated the rpyc server:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts\rpyc_classic.py --host="0.0.0.0"
```

However, on the remote machine I cannot see the messageBox but only the process that suppose to create it.

I guess it's relate to the fact that my process runs from the server side under rpyc process (which is python.exe) ?

I've checked that the process is running on current logged-on user.

Perhaps it's some sort of rpyc configuration that I'm missing here ?

thanks